# Listing all TREs in a NITF with GDAL?

Tags: python, gdal, nitf

I am dealing with some NITF data that has a number of esoteric Tagged Record Extensions (TRE).  There is a lot of content out there about how to use `gdal` to create a NITF, but I can't find anything on how to do a full TRE dump (whether supported (structured) or unsupported (unstructured)).

So doing this

```
from osgeo import gdal

nitf_file = "C:/Temp/file_a.nitf"

r = gdal.Open(nitf_file)
md = r.GetMetadata()
```

will get the NITF metadata without issue.  But how do I read the TREs?

Python preferred, but a CLI solution is fine too.

Comment: Does this still work https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55968452/how-to-add-tre-to-nitf-image-files-in-gdal? Is this related https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/pull/2983/files/89a3c702833de7e73bae064ad5a465580049da2d? Perhaps you should give more details about the data that you have.

Comment: Yes, however there are a number of TREs that are not being returned (I am verifying with an existing utility that detects them all).  I am looking how to get into all of it.

Comment: It may be helpful for me to know how to simply get all textual header data out of a NITF.  For example, iterating over `md.items()` only reveals a small subset of data, while `tres = r.GetMetadata("xml:TRE")` returns a larger set (but not all header data).

Comment: I suppose you can't, the documentation https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/nitf.html says "Most file header and image header fields are returned as dataset level metadata", not "all". What is not tested is not guaranteed to work so I suggest to have a look at the test suite https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/autotest/gdrivers/nitf.py. Source code may also have helpful comments https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/tree/master/gdal/frmts/nitf.

Answer (score 2):

You can't dump TREs in general, because they can contain anything. There is absolutely no guarantee that the format is text, and a number of TREs do use binary encoding. For example, CCINFA can contain gzip encoded data.

The implementation in GDAL works off an XML description of the TRE format, which is in the source code as https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/gdal/data/nitf_spec.xml and is somewhere in your GDAL install `data` directory. You can extend that if you know what the format is.

Assuming that the length is fixed of 100 bytes (not counting the 6 bytes for the CETAG (maybe RETAG in your case) and 5 bytes for CELEN (or RELEN), you could extend it to support a hypothetical `MYTREA` TRE with something like:

```
<tre name="MYTREA" location="image">
    <field name="UNKNOWN" length="100" type="string"/>
</tre>
```

There are other structures that can be used for looping, fields with lengths determined by other fields, and conditional cases. Probably you can model it off other ones.

So you should find your copy of `nitf_spec.xml` (e.g. in `/usr/share/gdal/nitf_spec.xml` on Debian/Ubuntu), and add that entry (adapted to use whatever your TRE is called instead of `MYTREA`). You can then use gdalinfo or other tools (including code you wrote) to show the TRE. You don't need to recompile - its read at run-time.

If you can say what the TREs are (and they are in STDI-0002 or otherwise public), it might be worth raising a ticket in GDAL. If it is for SNIP, you might want to upgrade your GDAL, since a lot of work got done on SNIP-related TREs recently.

Comment: The TRE is definitely text only, but I'm not sure I can share it.  I'll check through the data provider.  If I can, I'll file an issue on the github page.  Thanks!

Comment: What is the TRE identifier? If you open the text file, you'll (eventually) be able to find it followed by 5 numbers (which is the length of the body of the TRE). It would obviously be better if there was a public sample, but as long as the definition is public and it isn't too complex, implementing it blind isn't that bad.

Comment: So, it's definitely not STDI-0002/public.  If I can get explicit guidance from the data provider, I'll post a feature request over at GH issues.

Comment: @auslander What was the outcome on this?

Comment: it's a non-public TRE, so I can't request it in GDAL :(

Comment: I'm not sure how to provide a better answer without any more detail. Is it fixed length and always text?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's fixed length, but it's always text, yes.  I would of course not blame you for not providing an answer, because I can't provide the schema.

Comment: I've dropped in a skeleton TRE definition. Maybe that helps.

Comment: Thanks!  I'll see if I can't grab src and compile locally.  Appreciate all the follow-up!

Comment: You shouldn't need to recompile - its an external file, loaded at run time. So you should be able to edit the file (or copy it and set `GDAL_DATA` if you're on a locked-down environment).

Comment: Could we do a direct messaging session at some point?  I'm a little unclear how I'd implement this, even generically, in python.

Comment: I won't do private support for free, sorry. I have updated the answer to show how to make the change. You don't need python at this point - just edit the XML.

Comment: Understand. Still appreciate it! I'll give this a shot on Monday when I'm back in the office.